# Angular firebase hosting AT(...)firestore is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I created angular application for test firebase functions and I deployed this app on firebase hosting. Almost everything working expect firestore function.
This is the error

```
main.8ae925009adf8b80e1bc.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: AT(...).firestore is not a function
TypeError: AT(...).firestore is not a function
```

I don't know why this error occurse. On my local enviroment everything work poperly. This is link for app https://elevated-analog-119716.firebaseapp.com

I use this library

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/cdk": "~7.3.7",
"@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/http": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
"@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
"@ngxs/store": "^3.4.3",
"angularfire2": "^5.2.1",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"firebase": "^6.2.2",
"nativescript-angular": "~7.2.0",
"nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
"reflect-metadata": "~0.1.12",
"rxjs": "~6.3.3",
"tns-core-modules": "~5.2.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.4",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "~0.8.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.20.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.1.1"
  }
```

This is my app module

```
    @NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    LayoutModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatListModule,
    HomeModule,
    PolicyListModule,
    MatTableModule,
    AddUserModule
  ],
  providers: [PolicyService, AngularFirestore],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

And this is usersService where I call for data

```
constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) {}
    getUsers(): Observable<any> {
        return this.firestore.collection('user', x => x.orderBy('jerk', 'asc')).snapshotChanges();
    }
```

And this is code from component

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.db.getUsers().subscribe(v => this.items = v.map(v =>{
      const data = v.payload.doc.data();
      data.id = v.payload.doc.id;
      return data;
    }));
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need provider `AngularFirestore` it is already declared in module `AngularFirestoreModule` remember right now you are importing wrong module. could be same about `PolicyService` but i'm not sure about that don't know this module.

By importing `AngularFireDatabaseModule` u wrighting querys like `this.db.list` or `this.db.object` and when u importing `AngularFirestoreModule` u wrighting querys like `this.db.collection` or if u need one document `this.db.doc`

Paste in service file:

```
  addKeyToObject = _ => {
    const object = _.payload.val()
    object.key = _.payload.key;
    return object;
  }

  constructor(private firestore: AngularFirestore) { }

  getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.firestore.collection('user', x => x.orderBy('jerk', 'asc')).snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map(actions => actions.map(this.addKeyToObject)))
  }
```

if this is an service file u may want to declare it in app.module.ts in `providers: [UsersService]`

in component.ts:

```
  users$: Observable<any[]>

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.users$ = this.db.getUsers()
  }
```

in template of this component:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
  <p>User id: {{user.id}}</p>
</div>
```

`| async` is a pipe it will prevent you from subscribing to an Observable.
If you really want to subscribe you need to unsubscribe to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When I remove AngularFirestore from providers I get error 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserService -> AngularFirestore]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserService -> AngularFirestore]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestore!
Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[UserService -> AngularFirestore]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[UserService -> AngularFirestore]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AngularFirestore!

Comment: It's started working when I run ng build --optimization=false

Comment: U got error because you are importing Real time database not Cloud store sorry didn't see that. You need to import `AngularFirestoreModule`.

Comment: By importing `AngularFireDatabaseModule` u wrighting querys like `this.db.list` or `this.db.object` and when u importing `AngularFirestoreModule` u wrighting querys like `this.db.collection` or if u need one document `this.db.doc`

Comment: Thank you for your help it's work now. Please add it into your main answer

Comment: Just to clearly get the point ,you guys are trying to say,  I'll say,  in app.module.ts , add `  import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore'; `   and put this AngularFirestoreModule in imports array.